# Bootstrap 4 pagination with CakePHP 2 pagination helper

Tags: pagination, cakephp-2.0, bootstrap-4

In CakePHP 2.x, I can use the below code to output pagination in Bootstrap 3 perfectly:

```
<ul class="pagination">
    <?php
    echo $this->Paginator->prev(__('Previous'), array('tag' => 'li'), null, array('tag' => 'li', 'class' => 'disabled', 'disabledTag' => 'a'));
    echo $this->Paginator->numbers(array('separator' => '', 'currentTag' => 'a', 'currentClass' => 'active', 'tag' => 'li', 'first' => 1, 'last' => 5, 'ellipsis' => '<li class="disabled"><a>...</a></li>'));
    echo $this->Paginator->next(__('Next'), array('tag' => 'li'), null, array('tag' => 'li', 'class' => 'disabled', 'disabledTag' => 'a'));
    ?>
</ul>
```

The output is:

```
<ul class="pagination">
    <li class="prev">
        <a href="/" rel="prev">Previous</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/">1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="active">
        <a>2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/services/index/page:3">3</a>
    </li>
    <li class="next">
        <a href="/services/index/page:3" currentClass="disabled" rel="next">Next</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

But now the Bootstrap 4 Beta is changed the structure with class inside each element like this:

```
<nav aria-label="...">
    <ul class="pagination">
        <li class="page-item disabled">
            <a class="page-link" href="#">Previous</a>
        </li>
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">1</a></li>
        <li class="page-item active">
            <a class="page-link" href="#">2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">3</a></li>
        <li class="page-item">
            <a class="page-link" href="#">Next</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Please help to set options of Paginator in CakePHP 2.x for the above output.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using the following code

```
<ul class="pagination">
<?php
    echo $this->Paginator->prev('< ' . __('Previous'), array('tag' => 'li', 'class'=>'page-item', ' class'=>'page-link'), null, array('class' => 'disabled page-item', 'tag' => 'li', 'disabledTag' => 'a', ' class' =>'page-link'));
    echo $this->Paginator->numbers(array('separator' => '', 'currentTag' => 'a', 'tag' => 'li', 'class'=>'page-item',  'currentClass' => 'disabled page-link', ' class'=>'page-link'));
    echo $this->Paginator->next(__('Next') . ' >', array('tag' => 'li', 'class'=>'page-item', ' class'=>'page-link'), null, array('class' => 'disabled page-item', 'tag' => 'li', 'disabledTag' => 'a', 'currentClass'=>'page-link', ' class' =>'page-link'));
?> </ul>
```

The key is to use an element of the array called ' class', and put the bootstrap classes there